# How is it possible for the composite function to be continuous in this case?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity, graphing-functions, function-and-relation-composition

When
$f(x) = x^2+3x+1 (x\geq1), x+2(x<1)$,
$g(t) = ㅣ3t-12ㅣ$,
$t=f(x)$
In this case, how can $g(f(x))$ be define between when $f(x)= [3,5]$?

$f(x)$ do not have $3<f(x)\leq5$ as a result.
so $g(t)$ do not have $[3,5]$ for its domain. But when I plotted the graph of $g(f(x))$, it's even continuous for every real number. Can I know what I misunderstood?

Comment: Is that what you meant ?

Comment: yes thank you:)

Comment: But the edit wasn't accepted... I suggested an edit but no one accepted it.

Comment: Should I make the edits once again ?

Comment: I am not sure about the interval... I leave it to the others to correct.

Comment: (3,5] is right, but its fine. thank you. I'm just curious about how can the composite function g(f(x)) is define for every real number.

Comment: Ok.. but I don't think I am the right person to ask to. I am just 15 years old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The composition of $\ g\ $ and $\ f\ $ is continuous because $\ g\ $ is continuous everywhere,  $\ f\ $ is continuous everywhere except at $\ x=1\ $, where it is continuous *from above*, and $\ \displaystyle g\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-}f(x)\right)=$$g(3)=$$3=$$g(5)=$$g(f(1))\ $.  Alternatively, by definition,
\begin{align}
g(f(x))&=|3f(x)-12|\\
&=\cases{|3x-6|&if $\ x<1$\\
    \left|3x^2+9x-9\right|&if $\ x\ge1\ $,}
\end{align}
so the graph of $\ y=g(f(x))\ $ is that of $\ y= |3f(x)-12|\ $ for $\ x<1\ $, and it is that of $\ y= \left|3x^2+9x-9\right|\ $ for $\ x\ge1\ $. But when $\ x=1\ $ the graphs of $\ y= |3f(x)-12|\ $ and $\ y= \left|3x^2+9x-9\right|\ $ *intersect* (namely at the point $\ (1,3)\ $), so the graph of $\ y=g(f(x))\ $ will have no jumps.